# What is the most appropiate word to name thr group between 55 and 75 years old?

Tags: nouns

I am creating a blog for people 55 and older to encourage them to share their experience and knowledge on the internet. Maybe it could be the Baby Boomers group, but that group goes around every year. I want to know what would be the most appropriate term to name people between 55 and 75 years old.

Comment: Other than Baby Boomers, what are some names you have found to describe this cohort that didn't work for you?

Comment: I was going to suggest "old farts", but maybe not.

Comment: Baby Boomers only form the top end of that age group. I'm 70 and I was at the tail end of the post-war baby boom (or Bulge as it was more commonly known in the UK). Some of the 55-year-olds would even be the children of Boomers. There was a small increase in the birth rate in the late 60s and early 70s as Boomers started to have children but it was preceded by a drop in the birth rate during the late 50s and early 60s. As most of the conscripts in Vietnam were Boomers that might have been different in the US.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. In USA Baby Boomers are people borne between 1946 and 1964. The most younger is 56 years old and each year, this age will increase, so the new 55 years old would be excluded.